# Finding Real root with Library functions

Tags: equation-solving

```
HW[m_] = m ( EllipticK[ 1/m^2] - EllipticE [1/m^2]) ;
Rad[m_] = m - Sqrt[m^2 - 1] ;
Plot[{HW[m], Rad[m], 0}, {m, 1.01, 6}, 
 PlotLabel -> "HW > Rad_ immer" , GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick]
FindRoot[HW[m] == 1.5 Rad[m] , {m, 3 - .05 I}]
```

The functions plot real values alright.However they do not together iterate well enough as above. What accuracy and initial value is to be supplied/perturbed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start with another inital value for `m`, it works flawlessly:

```
FindRoot[HW[m] == 1.5 Rad[m], {m, -1.1}]
(* {m -> -1.02646} *)
```

For some `m`s, e.g. -1.3, you might get miniscule imaginary parts due to the floating point operations involved, which can be cut off like so:

```
FindRoot[HW[m] == 1.5 Rad[m], {m, -1.3}] // Chop
(* {m -> -1.02646} *)
```

---

Besides: I would suggest using `SetDelayed` instead of `Set` for your functions like so:

```
HW[m_] := m (EllipticK[1/m^2] - EllipticE[1/m^2]);
Rad[m_] := m - Sqrt[m^2 - 1];
```

and maybe change your `Plot` command to

```
Plot[{HW[m], Rad[m]}, {m, 1.01, 6}, PlotLabel -> "HW > Rad_ immer", 
     PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}]
```

sparing you the hassle of having to add the constant 0 into the diagram.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted positive $m$ only. However,just after posting I plotted *ratio* HW[m]/Rad[m] to find that it tends asymptotically to $\pi/2$, which could not be readily judged looking at separate graphs :)

Comment: @Narasimham: You're welcome!